# Replacing commas in resultset with new line in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not had to do something like this in the past and am wondering if it is indeed possible. I am allowing multiple code numbers to be added in an  so long as they are delimited by commas. What I am wanting to do is upon the user clicking on the "okay" button that a  showing the numbers entered will show them one on top of each other with a "delete" button next to them. That part is easy...the hard part is getting the comma stripped out and the new line placed in its stead.

Are there any examples or samples that anyone can point me too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) using the `g` flag ("global") for the "search" part, and a replacement string of your choosing (from your question, I'm not sure whether you want `<br>` — e.g., an HTML line break — or `\n` which really is a newline [but remember newlines are treated like spaces in HTML]). E.g.:

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
numbers = numbers.replace(/,/g, '<br>'); // Or \n, depending on your needs
```

Or if you want to allow for spaces, you'd put optional spaces either side of the comma in the regex:

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
numbers = numbers.replace(/ *, */g, '<br>'); // Or \n, depending on your needs
```

Comment: Do you (or anyone) have (has) any idea about how to do the same in angular?

Comment: I did the exact same thing in angular and it is not working..so not sure if something is framework specific or not?

Comment: I am doing this --- val.replace(/,/g, '\n');
Where val has the value = 'I love,angular,2'

Comment: The response that I am getting is : 'I love angular 2'
All the commas are getting replaced by 'whitespaces'

Comment: @ShubhamArya - Of course. `\n` is a newline, which is whitespace. In web pages, all whitespace is rendered as a single space.

Comment: so If I want a new line, then how should I go about it?

Comment: @ShubhamArya - I suggest posting a question with a [mcve] of your situation (including Angular, Stack Snippets suppport Angular) asking how to do line breaks in your specific situation. Angular and most frameworks will need you to do something other than just HTML in the normal case.

Comment: I got it to work with the same approach...Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

To replace *all* occurrences of a string you need to use a regexp with the `g` (global) modifier:

```
var numlist = "1,4,6,7,3,34,34,634,34";
var numlistNewLine = numlist.replace(/,/g, '\n');
```

Alternatively, use `.split()` and `.join()`

```
var newList = numList.split(',').join('\n');
```

Comment: +1, `split` could well be a good alternative depending on what the OP wants to do with the result.

Answer (score -1):

```
var numlist = "1,4,6,7,3,34,34,634,34";

var numlistNewLine = numlist.replace(',','\n');
```

No jQuery needed. `String` has a nice `replace()` function for you.

Comment: @Alnitak: Can you explain why?  Just saying "won't work" isn't very helpful.

Comment: I didn't know replace only matched the first occurrence. You learn something new every day.