# Enter new line after every comma in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enter new line after every founded comma in my textarea.

```
<textarea id="update_destination" placeholder="Podpiete adresy" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

and there is how I fill my textarea

```
$("#update_destination").val(alias.destination);
```

alias is a object.

Now in my textarea I got something like xxx, yyy, zzz
I want to have:

xxx

yyy

zzz

Comment: so [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) comma with a new line \n

Comment: `STRING.replace(/,/g, "\n")`. In your case, use `alias.destination.replace(/,/g, "\n")` :)

Comment: @Profit great works fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing commas in resultset with new line in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018422/replacing-commas-in-resultset-with-new-line-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#update_destination').val(alias.destination.split(",").join("\n"));
```

You can check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/ho9mneat/1/) for your ease

Can refer to [this Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606289/5179633) for more detail about `replace all occurrences of all string`